# Can a professor take a full-time 12 months industry job (get fully paid) while on one-year sabbatical?

Tags: sabbatical

Assuming the home university only pays 1/2 of 9-months salary in the period of one-year sabbatical.

Can it be legally allowed? or does it violate any rules in general? What would be the worst consequence if doing so?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that question is the same or very similar, but it was not effectively answered.

Comment: Hi walksouth, the reason that the other question might not have been properly answered is becasue the answer to your question is specific to the country and institituion you are working at. You, yourself are asking "*Does it violate any rules*" and "*can it be legally allowed?*". We can't answer this without knowing the specific rules of your institutions. Therefore the anwer in the other question is correct insofar that "Ask your institution" is the only reasonable advice we can give you. Only they know what is allowed and what is not.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I mean "US universities". I checked the faculty handbook of my university but failed to find any relevant information (to this question). That's why I asked here to see there exist any "general" rules for such cases at US Universities.

Answer (score 3):

The only legal rules that are likely to apply here are the contractual rules for the terms of the professor's employment with the university, combined with the university's policy/contract relating to sabbaticals.  Whether or not this is allowed would depend on the terms of the sabbatical, as set out in the appropriate university policies and employment contract.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible; ask your HR department whether it is possible for you.